# function call operator in class or method?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class foo
{
public:
    struct bar
    {
        bar() {}
        int bar_var;
    };

    operator std::vector<bar>() {
        return m_list;
    }

private:
    std::vector<bar> m_list;
    int foo_var;
};
```

Here defined a class foo, what is the semantic "operator std:vector<bar>()" mean here? I don't think it is an overloaded function call operator.

Compile with the above code works OK

Answer (score 5):

> what is the semantic "operator std:vector()" mean here?

It denotes a [**conversion operator**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) that allows you to use a `foo` object where a `std::vector<bar>` is expected. A conversion operator is a special kind of member function that converts a value of a ***class type*** to a value of some other type.

For example, say we have a function called `func` that takes a `std::vector<foo::bar>` as its only parameter. Now,
you can even call this function by passing a `foo` object instead of passing a `std::vector<foo::bar>` as shown below:

```
//--------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv----------> expects std::vector<foo::bar> 
void func(std::vector<foo::bar> m)
{
    std::cout<<"func called"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    foo fObject;
//-------vvvvvvv---->passing a foo object which implicitly uses the conversion operator    
    func(fObject); 
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZzdpwCPN1)

In the above demo, `func` expects a `std::vector<foo::bar>`. But we're passing `fObject` which is an object of type `foo` and so there will be an **implicit conversion** of `fObject` to `std::vector<foo::bar>` using the conversion operator that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). In your example, a `foo` will happily call that function if it's ever used in a context where a `std::vector<bar>` is expected. A more typical use case might look something like

```cpp
class MyCustomNumberType {
private:
  // Super secret number arithmetic stuff.
public:
  operator double() {
    // Convert to a double and return here...
  }
}

MyCustomNumberType foo = /* more complicated math ... */;
double bar = foo + 1.0;
```