# C++ - Class implicitly convertible to size_t

Tags: c++, class

I have created a simple class and I would like it to be convertible to size_t. But I don't understand how to do it.

```cpp
class MyClass {
private:
    std::size_t size;
public:
    MyClass();
    ~Myclass();
};
```

I tried this got some errors :

```
Error: namespace std has no member class size_t
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you include the header for `std::size_t`? You'll also need a conversion operator: `operator std::size_t`.

Comment: Yes I do. I put #include <cstddef>

Comment: Please create a proper [mre], then [edit] your question to copy-paste it into the question. Also please copy-paste the full and complete build-log from the shown example.

Comment: @Teamもののけ姫 Why is it not in the question? It should be.

Comment: @Teamもののけ姫 The technical term for what you're looking for is *"conversion operator"*. Search that term and you'll find plenty of dupes and examples for this trivial task. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71566446/12002570). Also refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) can be found in multiple headers, for example `<cstddef>`

To enable the conversion, you can provide a `operator std::size_t` member function :

```
#include <cstddef>

class MyClass {
private:
    std::size_t size;
public:
    operator std::size_t() const {
        return this->size;
    }
    //...
};
```

the compiler will call the member function when needed:

```
int main() {
    MyClass foo;
    std::size_t s = foo;
}
```

Comment: Mmh I see. I thought we could write this way: ```class MyClass : std::size_t```

Comment: no, you can't inherit from primitive types.

Comment: @Teamもののけ姫 if it answers you question, don't forget to accept it and upvote, so others can see what helps in the similar situation